# "µamera" problem on S3

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, data-recovery, photos

I am using an SD card on galaxy S3 - I store my photos on here. But today, on the DCIM folder of that card, I see a folder that named "µamera" and all of my photos were gone.

It seems that, this issue is somehow common, if you google "µamera" you'll see that.

I am trying to recover photos from SD card but it seems SD card is not readable by PC. However, I can see the all other files in the SD card from the phone, even other photos which are not in DCIM folder (that is current camera folder). The problem is only the DCIM folder which camera writes photos.

Does anyone have an idea about this problem and solution? I am also open to good advice on recovering files on S3. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried accessing that folder using a file manager directly on the device, e.g. [ES File Explorer](http://www.appbrain.com/app/es-file-explorer-file-manager/com.estrongs.android.pop)?

Comment: yes it didn't worked. It turns out that, they were all in the LOST.DIR folder -- so taking them from LOST.DIR folder and rename the files in that folder with .jpg extension recovers the images. For whom interested.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Mark! As this perfectly answers your question: Please post that as answer below, and accept it. That way other people running into a similar issue see here's a solution available; currently your question is still listed as "having no answer".

Comment: Wonderful! Just upvoted it. More of that :) Or, in other words: Don't forget us, but return here anytime!

Comment: Related: [Self replicating worm in sd card](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/92877/self-replicating-worm-in-sd-card)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that, they were all in the LOST.DIR folder with arbitrary names (numbers) -- so taking them from LOST.DIR folder and rename the files in that folder with .jpg extension recovers the images. For whom interested.

Comment: I was [looking in to this the other day](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/92877/self-replicating-worm-in-sd-card). Usually when you see the folders renamed with "µ" at the beginning, it usually means the sdcard is corrupting. It may be time to think about purchasing a new one.