# Self replicating worm in sd card

Tags: sd-card, file-system, files

I have a Samsung Galaxy Grand with a 16gb micro-sd card. For some inexplicable reason, I am losing data on the sd card. Folder names are being changed to start with the character "μ." For example, my_music was changed to μy_music (this does not happen on the device's internal memory). There are more than 960 files with the name "μ" and it is replicating itself. Is it a problem with the Micro SD card or something else such as the phone itself? Is there any way I can fix this other than formatting?

Comment: I have read on some [forums](http://forums.androidcentral.com/verizon-galaxy-s-iii/248985-strange-folder-names-microsd-card.html) while searching for your issue that it can be caused by a corrupt sdcard. Is the card a SanDisk? Check in LOST.DIR folder and see if there are "lost" files in there.

Comment: @Ryan: I checked the LOST.DIR folder and i found all my media and other lost files, though in an unreadable/unopenable format..
kindly suggest what to do next!

thankx in advance

Comment: It might be time to try another SD card. That would be the quickest way to check. It could well be corrupt, especially if it is old. Borrow one from a friend, or buy a new one and see how you get on.

Comment: Related: ['µamera' problem on S3](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/61989/%C2%B5amera-problem-on-s3/93541#comment117214_93541)

Answer (score 0):

Check for suspicious applications you may have installed recently. Also this behaviour is very weird as it should usually do that on the internal sd card where it could harm your device and not on the external one where it only annoys the user.

About the "self replicating": If you know in what file the worm is located and checked if all files are the same then deleting that file and formatting your sd card may be the solution to your issue.